# jquery accordion not working some times

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

my problem is when i declared like this .. that not working some times..

```
 $("#accordion").accordion();
    $(function() {
      $( "#accordion").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            show: "blind",
            width: 350,
            minHeight:460,
            hide: "explode"
        });

     });
```

if i removed wrapping the code in function .. it works well all time..

```
$(function(){

});
```

whats the problem in this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    $( "#accordion").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        show: "blind",
        width: 350,
        minHeight:460,
        hide: "explode"
    });
});
```

`$(function() {` is a short cut for `$(document).ready(...)`, which means the wrapped code should be executed only after the dom is ready. So it have to wrap your code and it should not be used inside your code.

Comment: thanks for quick reply..agree with your answer..why some times it works?

Comment: where is the script kept, in header/at the bottom of body

Comment: It looks like the dialog should work always, but the accordion fails, is it correct?

Comment: this script is placed at the top..no no dialog is failing ,accordian is working properly..when i removed $(function(){}); it works well..

Comment: other than jQuery r u using any other libraries